# Laravel 5.1: Call to undefined function dropColumn() with phpArtisan

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, database-migration, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to learn the Laravel 5.1 framework, which is amazing. I'm following the tutorials of Jeffrey Way on laracasts.com. Only now i have come across a problem that i can't seem to get rid of.

I was following the tutorial and i tried to do a migrate:refresh with the php artisan, which should work, but i get this error all the time:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6MX0.png)

And for the love of god, i can't figure out what the problem is. This is how my migration looks like:

[Migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IFQ9.png)

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably have a problem in users migration. Check it.

Comment: The users migration was pre-made when I installed Laravel 5.1. I didn't touch it at all. This is how it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/pOrQFMP.png

Comment: Nvm, found the problem. Typo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the error is from one of your other migration files.

> The migrate:refresh command will first roll back **ALL** of your database
>   migrations, and then run the migrate command.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem in another migration. Typo :)